# How to batch update datas in ContentProvider,something confused me

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

How can i execute this sql in content Provider as below:

```
update dtrips set dtp_day_idx=dtp_day_idx+2 where tp_id=1
```

Can anyone help me fix the code

```
    DTrip dTrip = new DTrip();
    ContentValues values = createContentValues(dTrip);
    values.put("dtp_day_idx" ,...);
    String select ="tp_id="+tripId;
    mContentResolver.update(UsersColumns.CONTENT_URI, values, select, null);
```

Thanks.