# How to update datas with ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

How can I execute this sql with Content Provider as below:

```
update dtrips set dtp_day_idx=dtp_day_idx+2 where tp_id=1
```

My java code is like this

```
    DTrip dTrip = new DTrip();
    ContentValues values = createContentValues(dTrip);
    values.put("dtp_day_idx" ,...);
    String select ="tp_id="+tripId;
    mContentResolver.update(DTripColumns.CONTENT_URI, values, select, null);
```

Can anyone help me fix the code?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify where the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to batch update datas in ContentProvider,something confused me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155395/how-to-batch-update-datas-in-contentprovider-something-confused-me)

Answer (score 1):

Append the ID for the row to the content URI like this: (assuming DTripColumns.CONTENT_URI is the content URI of your provider)

```
final Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DTripColumns.CONTENT_URI, tripId);
mContentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null);
```

Here is more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html